# Disable local user PAM, enable root user with LDAP

Tags: users, login, root, pam

I am trying to set up a Linux machine with LDAP authentication and root account enabled. There is no issue with the LDAP server and everything works fine.

I wanted to disable local users, so I tried editing PAM. I tried using pam-auth-update and unticking the "Unix authentication". Local users are successfully denied, but so is the root account.

I am now trying different things at the `pam.d` files,
but it seems I screwed up multiple times and don't know what am I doing.

Editing the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file:

```
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
```

After I added this line, there is no password prompt and it logs in directly.

```
auth     pam_succeed_if.so    uid = 0 quiet
```

I added this line and it does nothing.
I am now reading the PAM configuration. 
Could anyone help me understand and solve my problem?

Comment: Should that line have a `sufficient` in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this (at the beginning of the file) to prevent local users (except root) to login.

```
auth [success=1   default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 quiet       
auth [success=die default=ignore] pam_localuser.so
```

The first line skips the second line if root and the second prevents local users (in `/etc/passwd`) from login. Non-local users should not be affected.